# Using Jersey and Spring in a Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jersey

I want to create a REST web service using Jersey. I also want to use Spring in the project.  Now, my questions is the following:

1. I don't see any reason for integrating these 2 together in my application.  So, I should be able to use Spring for bean management and Jersey for creating  the web service.  Am I correct, or Spring and Jersey somehow have to be integrated.
2. I see that there is a jersey-spring maven project, and so, I assume that this is for the purpose of integrating jersey and spring together. My question here is do I get any benefit of using this integrated form rather than simply use Jersey and Spring separately each for its own functionality?

Thanks,
Cyrus

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely combine the two projects. However, I would encourage you to look at Spring-MVC for doing REST as it is very powerful and easy to use. If memory serves, the jersey-spring project was helpful in integration of JAXB and other touch points.  Again, this is all built into Spring.  And if you use Spring-Boot it is amazingly simple to get running.

Comment: I do agree that Spring-MVC is powerful; however, it is not an implementation of REST.  And I also have looked at Spring-REST; but the problem is that Spring-REST is not JAX-RS compliant.

Answer (score 1):

The jersey-spring project provides integration between Jersey and Spring. It allows you to wire in any beans in your Spring context into Jersey and vice-versa.

For instance, if you are using spring-security, it will provide your spring-security principal when wiring the Jersey specific SecurityContext into any of your REST resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Spring beans from your Jersey REST endpoints (or use Spring Beans as implementations for your JAX-RS interfaces) you need to integrate Spring and Jersey, otherwise it won't work. If you don't have any connections between Spring beans and your REST endpoints, then it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first statement is correct. I have used Jersey and Sprint as separate entities.

- Jersey is really awesome to create a web server.
- Spring is useful for dependency injection (beans) and other cools stuff.

About your second statement, I do not know anything jersey-spring maven project.

My suggestion/opinion is to do as your first comment. Use them in a separate way. You will have the best of both worlds. Using jersey-spring maven project might be a complication and maybe it is not what you want. Libraries usually are intend to be independent.